# Migrating ServiceStack project from mono to .NET Core /Standard

Tags: .net, mono, servicestack, .net-core, .net-standard

We deploy our project to mono environments. We target .NET 4.5.
Now we are starting second project, which will have same ServiceModel as our current project. We are experimenting with .NET Core.

Is it possible to share ServiceModel dll between .NET Core and .NET 4.5 applications? 
I have found that I can make .NET Standard library which targets both and reference ServiceStack for .NET 4.5, and ServiceStack.Core for .NET Core.

Now we are compiling: for mono on mono, and for windows on windows.
If I understand correctly, in .NET Standard scenario we will be forced to compile on windows only, then pick up right dlls and deploy to linux.

Are there any known problems with this approach?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to share ServiceModel dll between .NET Core and .NET 4.5 applications? I have found that I can make .NET Standard library which targets both and reference ServiceStack for .NET 4.5, and ServiceStack.Core for .NET Core.

Currently .NET 4.5 ServiceModel projects require a dependency on the ServiceStack.Interfaces PCL NuGet package/dll whilst .NET Core ServiceModel projects require a dependency on the ServiceStack.Interfaces.Core .NET Standard 1.1 NuGet package/dll. You could multi target your ServiceModel project using VS2017 new MSBuild project format and share the project that way or sharing a multi target NuGet package providing builds for both .NET 4.5 and .NET Core.

The alternative is to use [Add ServiceStack Reference](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-add-servicestack-reference) to share your Server DTOs by source code to different .NET 4.5 or .NET Core clients (I.e. instead of sharing your Service Model.dll) which will work because the source code is 100% compatible.

Note after .NET Core and .NET Standard v2 is released we'll be merging ServiceStack's .NET and .NET Core NuGet packages together in a major v5 release of ServiceStack which will only have .NET Standard version of ServiceStack.Interfaces so you will be able to freely share your ServiceModel .Dll between .NET 4.5 and .NET Core projects without issue.